# Naming/formatting standard for global variables

Tags: javascript, global-variables

What is both the naming and formatting standard for global variables in JavaScript?

For example:

```
var global_var // ?
var _global_var // ?
var GLOBAL_VAR // ?
var _GLOBAL_VAR // ?
...
```

Note: I am NOT talking about constants, just simply variables that have global scope.

Comment: Warning: you are going to get a lot of snarky comments about how you should never, never, ever, never, ever, never use global variables.  Just ignore them, as that has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Thanks. (I see little difference between a private class variable and a global javascript variable.)

Comment: BTW, (at the moment) there is no such thing as a constant in JavaScript (though `constant` is a reserved keyword per spec).

Answer (score 19):

There are no standards as such. The most common practice is to use lower camel case (e.g. `var fooBarBaz;`) for all variables and property names, irrespective of scope, but this is by no means universal. The only exception is to capitalize the name of a function that is intended to be used as a constructor:

```
function SomeClass() {}

var someClassObj = new SomeClass();
```

I've also seen block capitals and underscores used for variables that the author considers constants, or alternatively for all global variables:

```
var EARTH_RADIUS = 6378100;
```

Another reasonably common convention (although not one I use myself) is to prefix properties of objects that author wishes to be considered private with an underscore:

```
this._leaveThisAlone = "Magical property";
```

Douglas Crockford published [his own take on JavaScript code standards](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) several years ago that covers most of this, but as ever this is just one man's opinion, so take with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Per the article you linked to, it states **"Global variables should be in all caps"**.  This is contrary to what you stated above.

Comment: Well, there you go. As I say, there's no official standard, and Crockford has his own views that not everyone shares.

Comment: All caps is the same as var EARTH_RADIUS in my opinion.  How else can you show that they are separate words if not through capitalization?

Comment: As Tim Down said there's no real standards for JavaScript so your best bet is to borrow them from C++ as most programmers are familiar with C++.  In the end it doesn't matter as long as everyone on the team agrees on what to do though.

Comment: @hyprsleepy: “most programmers are familiar with C++” → Well, at least *not* those who code in JavaScript, I fear, as many websites show coding skills of someone who is not familiar in *any* programming language.

Answer (score 4):

The requisite comment about rethinking the design if you're needing to use global variables, blah blah...

The global variables I've seen are normally prefixed with `g` or `gbl`. Sometimes this is modified with an underscore: `_g`, `_gbl`. IIRC, the underscores were used when 'global' was confined to some scope and not 'truly' global.

If you are going to use a global variable in a fashion where EVERYTHING shouldn't be able to use the variable, I'd go with using the underscore. In javascript (IIRC) the convention of using an underscore as a prefix implies that the variable is 'private' or shouldn't be used externally. If you are, alternately, declaring it in a fashion that everyone should be able to access and modify then I'd go with just the prefix and no underscore.

Answer (score 0):

One big reason people would tell you to not use global variables is to avoid interfering with other scripts and/or libraries.

A convention I started using when I need to use a global variable is to add my last name - this way I know I won't interfere with any libraries' or outside scripts' global variables.  (Though I have a fairly unique last name - this might not work if you're a Smith).

So my global variables would be named:

```
var foo_lastnameGlobal;
var bar_lastnameGlobal;
```

I should point out (in case it isn't clear) this is just a personal convention, not a common or widely used one.  It also helps me remember what my global variables are when I do use them.  I suppose it might not be so great for public code or in a professional group work environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two intents of doing such a thing.

The first reason to do such a thing is to be able to discover your global state variables bound to global object(usually window or global) at a given time. The problem is that no matter how rigorous you are, there are only two practical ways of approaching this; first is to create a global variable to keep track of global variables by name and commit to always changing it whenever you add/remove a global, second is to keep a copy of initial state of global and figure out which properties were added, removed, or changed since start.

The second reason to do such a thing is to emphasize in the code that it intentionally  interacting with the global state. In this case, there is no standard, little benefit to doing this over adding comments or explicitly specifying the global object rather than doing so implicitly.

There is a lot of punishment for having inconsistent notation across code if you decide to change the way you denote a constant between files or projects. There are plenty of notations to choose from, and all of them fail one way or another, either by obfuscating the variable name and it's natural alphabetic ordering, or adding additional referencing overhead.

Personally, if in doubt, I like to stick to the [Linux Kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html), I find it tackles many problems sufficiently.

> C is a Spartan language, and so should your naming be. Unlike Modula-2
>   and Pascal programmers, C programmers do not use cute names like
>   ThisVariableIsATemporaryCounter. A C programmer would call that
>   variable tmp, which is much easier to write, and not the least more
>   difficult to understand.
>
> HOWEVER, while mixed-case names are frowned upon, descriptive names
>   for global variables are a must. To call a global function foo is a
>   shooting offense.
>
> GLOBAL variables (to be used only if you really need them) need to
>   have descriptive names, as do global functions. If you have a function
>   that counts the number of active users, you should call that
>   count_active_users() or similar, you should not call it cntusr().
>
> Encoding the type of a function into the name (so-called Hungarian
>   notation) is brain damaged - the compiler knows the types anyway and
>   can check those, and it only confuses the programmer. No wonder
>   MicroSoft makes buggy programs.
>
> LOCAL variable names should be short, and to the point. If you have
>   some random integer loop counter, it should probably be called i.
>   Calling it loop_counter is non-productive, if there is no chance of it
>   being mis-understood. Similarly, tmp can be just about any type of
>   variable that is used to hold a temporary value.
>
> If you are afraid to mix up your local variable names, you have
>   another problem, which is called the function-growth-hormone-imbalance
>   syndrome. See chapter 6 (Functions).

Comment: I don't agree with the quote that "C programmers do not use cute names like `ThisVariableIsATemporaryCounter`". First, that's a ridiculous example, no one would call a variable by that name. However if that counter counts foo objects, then `foo_count` is a much better name than `tmp`. Many (I'm _guessing_ most) companies lean towards naming verbosity over brevity. E.g. [Google's c++ style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Naming). My experience in all places I worked at and wrote C++ for in the last (almost) 20 years it was the same.

Comment: @sprite This answer is 3 years old. I agree it is poorly written as it gives me a headache to read now. I have come to learn that humans can adapt to almost everything and you can justify both short and long names with all kinds of notations and abbreviations, the biggest issue is being consistent. No matter what you do many will never accept your convention even though it is consistent just because they are used to doing it differently. No matter how good your variable name is, the intent is not going to be evident without documentation or inspection.

Answer (score 0):

Not a standard but some ideas: `G_variable_name`, `g_variableName`, `gVARIABLE_NAME`.

Answer (score -3):

If you want employeeID to be a global variable then the The correct method is to declare as
window.employeeID = 5;
and then use window.employeeID in all the places you would access later.

Comment: You imply this is the _only_ correct method, which is false. Declaring a variable outside a function scope also attaches the variable to the window object, so it is a sort of shorthand. Both are correct.

`var GLOBAL_VAR = "foo";`
`//same as`
`window.GLOBAL_VAR = "foo";`